# Error 404 when uploading a file caused by error in update function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, dropzone.js

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out what's wrong in my code. Basically, I'm using `Dropzone-js's` file uploader, that uses drag and drop.  I can't upload a file because it returns me a `404 error`.
I searched through my logs and found that I had a problem in my `controller`, in the `update` function.

**The controller** :

```
class ChatRoomsController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!
before_action :set_room, only: [:index, :new, :create, :show, :edit, :signal]
before_action :set_participant, only: [:signal]

def index
  @chat_rooms = ChatRoom.all
end

def show
  # Show room messages
  @chat_room = ChatRoom.includes(:messages).find_by(id: params[:id])
  @message = Message.new

  @chat_room.participant?(current_user)

  # TODO: get participant only once
  if params[:guid]
    if @participant = User.find(params[:guid])
      @participant.joined_at = Time.now
      @chat_room.add_to_call(@participant)
    end
  elsif params[:del]
    if @participant = User.find(params[:del])
      @chat_room.remove_from_call(@participant)
    end
  end

  response = {
      room: @chat_room,
      # Get all call participants
      users: @chat_room.call_users,
      signals: deliver_signals!
  }

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: response }
  end

end

def new
  @chat_room = ChatRoom.new
end

def edit
  # Empty
end

def create
  @chat_room = current_user.chat_rooms.build(chat_room_params)
  if @chat_room.save
    @group_room.users << current_user
    redirect_to chat_rooms_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def update
  @chat_room = ChatRoom.find(id: params[:chat_room_id])
  if @chat_room.update_resource(chat_room_params)
    flash[:success] = 'test'
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def signal
  signal = signal_params
  signal[:chat_room] = @chat_room
  signal[:sender] = User.find(signal[:sender])
  signal[:recipient] = @participant
  logger.info('Signal is ' + signal.to_param)
  ChatRoomSignal.create! signal
  head 204
end

def deliver_signals!
  data = ChatRoomSignal.where recipient: @participant

  # Destroy the signals as we return them, since they have been delivered
  result = []
  data.each do |signal|
    result << {
        signal_type: signal.signal_type,
        sender_guid: signal.sender_id,
        recipient_guid: signal.recipient_id,
        data: signal.data,
        chat_room_id: signal.chat_room_id,
        timestamp: signal.created_at
    }
  end
  data.delete_all
  result
end

private

def set_participant
  @participant = User.find(params[:user_id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  # Retry with ID as GUID
  @participant = User.where(id: params[:user_id]).first
  raise unless @participant
end

def set_room
  @chat_room = ChatRoom.includes(:messages).find_by(id: params[:chat_room_id])
end

def chat_room_params
  params.require(:chat_room).permit(:title, :image)
end

def signal_params
  params.permit(:sender, :signal_type, :data)
end
```

**HTML code for file upload** :

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <%= form_for @chat_room, html: { multipart: true, class: "dropzone", id: "my-dropzone"} do |f| %>

    <div class="dz-message needsclick">
      <h3>Drop a file here</h3> or <strong>click</strong> to upload
    </div>

    <div class="fallback">
      <% f.file_field :image, as: :file %>
      <%= f.submit "Upload your file" %>
    </div>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

**The error :**

```
[ActionCable] [test@test.com] ChatRoomsChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
[ActionCable] [test@test.com] ChatRoomsChannel is streaming from chat_rooms_1_channel
Started PATCH "/chat_rooms/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-09 01:44:26 +0200
Processing by ChatRoomsController#update as JSON
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"p8KEWBx7fmJmEhHgINmp5rnj+PVwGXfbPHxslSaA4Z/5zA6HIJzxeBjwcz/+GcDEQKKwPwjXNJVnBtfq7xu2qw==", "chat_rooms"=>{"image"=>#    <ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f640e58f5b0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20170609-2887-1nuat54.png>, @original_filename="Screenshot from 2017-04-12 12-47-21.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"chat_rooms[image]\"; filename=\"Screenshot from 2017-04-12 12-47-21.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">}, "id"=>"1"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mChatRoom Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "chat_rooms".* FROM "chat_rooms" WHERE "chat_rooms"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find ChatRoom with 'id'={:id=>nil}):

app/controllers/chat_rooms_controller.rb:62:in `update'
```

**Line 62** :

```
@chat_room = ChatRoom.find(id: params[:chat_room_id])
```

So it seems like my `controller` is not able to find the `id` parameter, but i don't understand why. And this is probably the error that causes my file to return `404 error`.

Thanks for the time you will take to read my post.

Comment: What does the log shows? Check parameters, most likely is that you are not getting any value in `chat_room_id` key.

Comment: Updated error logs

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong key to get the `id`, try with `params[:id]`:

```
@chat_room = ChatRoom.find(params[:id])
```

Also notice that the `id:` has been removed, since `find` will look for the `id` provided as parameter.

Also, you should update your `chat_room_params` method:

```
def chat_room_params
 params.require(:chat_rooms).permit(:title, :image)
end
```

---

Since you are updating only 2 attributes, you could refactor your `update` method like this:

```
def update
  @chat_room = ChatRoom.find(id: params[:chat_room_id])
  @chat_room.title = chat_room_params[:title]
  @chat_room.image = chat_room_params[:image]

  if @chat_room.save(chat_room_params)
    flash[:success] = 'test'
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok so it seems like you are onto something. I have a new error now : ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find ChatRoom with 'id'={:id=>"1"}): 
But i don't really understand it, my current chat_room has an id equal to 1, so i don't get why it search id => 1

Comment: @xZeasy Check updated answer, removed the `id:` from `find`, which causes the error.

Comment: And there is another new error : ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: chat_room):
And now i have an error 400 bad request, no longer 404

Comment: It's ligne 115 "app/controllers/chat_rooms_controller.rb:115:in `chat_room_params'".
That's where the chat_room_params are, chat_room is a required parameter

Comment: @xZeasy i see now, you must update your `chat_room_params` with `require(:chat_rooms)`.

Comment: You mean when i try to call `chat_room_params` with this line `if @chat_room.update_resource(chat_room_params)` ?

Comment: @xZeasy No, i mean in your `chat_room_params` method, inside `require`.

Comment: so now my function line is equal to this : params.require(:chat_rooms).permit(:title, :image)`
But now i have this error : NoMethodError (undefined method `update_resource' for #<ChatRoom:0x007f640de8a968>
Did you mean?  update_columns):
  
app/controllers/chat_rooms_controller.rb:64:in update'`

Seems weird

Comment: Yes, follow the error advice: change it ti `update_columns`.

Comment: I don't think we are going the right way by changing that. Still i tried and it gives me this : `TypeError (no implicit conversion of ActionController::Parameters into String):`

Comment: I can't put you as the answer but still take my upvote, i think you put me on the right way with your original answer, i'll go from there, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your `params[:chat_room_id]` seems to be a hash..

Try

```
@chat_room = ChatRoom.find(id: params[:chat_room_id][:id])
```

Comment: got a "NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):", seems like it didn't like "[:id]"

Comment: @Gerry Doesn't work : ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find ChatRoom with 'id'=):